# If two sets of dates fall within another set of dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

See example below.

I need to show the true and false values as shown in the example.

The logic needs to make sure that "Start and End" falls within that columns time period. Column D's time period will therefore be 9th to 14th Dec, the next column (E) will be 15th to 20th December and so on. Think of it as a gantt chart showing timeframes.

[image: example]

Comment: What is "that week"?

Comment: So if the time period of start and end falls anywhere within (e.g) 9/12/2014 - 14/12/2014

Comment: I.e. your problem is to check whether one date is between other two?

Comment: Yes, but its not as simple as top date is inbetween start and end, because we have to consider the 10th - 14th as well..

Comment: "we have to consider the 10th - 14th as well"?

Comment: Look at my example.. we can't just take the 9th December, otherwise we disregard the 10th - 14th even though it still falls within that week.

Comment: But then the 16/12/2014 is in the same week as the 21/12/2014. Why is then there FALSE in your example?

Comment: Because the 16th falls within the week of the 15th.. not the 21st..

Comment: @AxelRichter, it seems the week ends on Friday or Saturday, so 21/12 is the next Sunday.

Comment: Its not about when the week ends.. its about when the next week starts.

Comment: This may surprise you, but when a week starts, the previous one ends. :P So I don't see the difference. We need to know if the week starts on Sunday, Monday or what.

Comment: Because the datas not necessarily weeks.. if I change the top to every other day, then your formula no longer works.

Comment: You said "sees whether it is within that week". Then I think you need to edit your question.

Comment: Considering your edited question, 9/12 is not between 10/12 and 2/1, 15/12 is not between 16/12 and 16/12. The logic is still not clear...

Comment: For me there is no logic in this. If the 09/12/2014 is in the same week as the 14/12/2014, then the 16/12/2014 also is in the same week as the 21/12/2014. Of course the 16/12/2014 also is in the same week as the 15/12/2014.

Comment: There's no logic if you are thinking about weeks, its all about the timeframes as I've stated before. Think of column D as 9 - 14th, column E as 15 - 20th, column F as 21 - 26th and so on..

Comment: Then you have only to check whether the start is lower or equal the day+5 and the end is greater or equal the day. `=AND($A2<=D$1+5,$B2>=D$1)`

Comment: Ok clearly you can't help. +5?! Its not always 5 days as explained before, there is no pattern to the days, meaning we just deal with the dates, I'll sort it myself and then provide an answer for anyone who might find value in this.

Comment: You mean the distance between the days may differ from column to column? Then your example was bad. `=AND($A2<=D$1+(E$1-D$1)-1,$B2>=D$1)` or `=AND($A2<E$1,$B2>=D$1)`

Comment: @AxelRichter, `D$1+(E$1-D$1)` = `D$1+E$1-D$1` = `E$1` :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my version

```
=AND(D$1<=$B2,E$1-1>=$A2)
```

See: [Check if two date ranges overlap](http://chandoo.org/wp/2010/06/01/date-overlap-formulas/)

Note: above formula can be shown to be equivalent to the 'NOT' form by using [De Morgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws)

Could also simplify further to

```
=AND(D$1<=$B2,E$1>$A2)
```

Comment: This seems to be the best option IMHO.

Comment: Best option, the one I originally marked as correct found to have errors in for previous dates - thanks Tom.

Answer (score 3):

Now that I see that the date ranges are defined by the values in row 1 and that the week concept is not involved at all, I changed the formula:

So, if you place this formula in `D2` and copy it in the range, you will get your result.

```
=OR(AND(D$1   >= $A2, D$1   <= $B2),
    AND(E$1   >  $A2, E$1-1 <= $B2),
    AND(D$1   <= $A2, E$1   >  $B2))
```

You just have to add a conditional formatting to get the color and you are done.

Edit: this can be really simplified like Tom Sharpe posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27174380/2321042):

```
=AND(D$1<=$B2,E$1-1>=$A2)
```

Comment: Well the dates may be random.. it can't be done by a certain day in the week.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't get you, but my answer seems to work though.

Comment: You have to know when your week ends and when it starts!

Comment: That's simply not true. You can compare dates as they all have a unique value in time.

Comment: I'm lost, I don't understand a word of what you mean. Doesn't my formula work for you? It does for me with your example.

Comment: I think your <= really need to be < (without equal) and remove the "-1" in the end of the range to ensure that you include the start and exclude the end of the range. I am hesitant to post my own answer as the OP appears to have ambiguous requirements.

Comment: I think @Andrew's answer is correct but if you compare something like this you can simplify the logic right down http://chandoo.org/wp/2010/06/01/date-overlap-formulas/

Comment: @theMayer, thanks for your comment. Actually I think only the `>=` could be simplified by removing the `-1`. My original logic took into consideration the chance of including time. But if time is always midnight, then this simplification can be done.

Comment: Times always get tricky, but that would be a valid assumption given the example; however, as noted the OP requires several "valid" assumptions to be made which turn out may not be valid. I think the question needs to be put on hold pending clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Following the Tom's comment (http://chandoo.org/wp/2010/06/01/date-overlap-formulas/), the simplified formula for cell D2 would be:

```
=NOT(OR($A2 >= E$1, $B2 < D$1))
```

This works well for datetimes or arbitrary numbers, not just for whole-day dates.

You will need 1 more column in the first row than the number of intervals checked.

Comment: Great simplification. One detail: it should be `$A8 > E$1-1`. Otherwise, you would be including a range that starts in the date in `E1`.

Comment: Having all dates with no time (midnight), a range of 15/12-20/12 returns TRUE for the 09/12-14/12 range (column D).